# how to change columns position in vb6?

Tags: vb6

I am working with a spread designer in visual basic 6 and am looking to change the display index of my table. I am adding extra columns and I need to rearrange them to match another form.

I am using visual basic 6 with spread designer 6.0
[image: with]

I have tried the below when loading the form:

```
lstTheLines.Col(1).DisplayIndex = 1
lstTheLines.Columns(25).DisplayIndex = 2
```

does anyone know how to do this without having to delete and re-add all columns?

Comment: Which of the 2 controls are you using?  And are you using data binding or loading the control manually?

Comment: I'm using the highlighted one (Farpoint Spread 6.0 (OLEDB), I'm manually loading it

Comment: I reviewed the documentation but I don't see anything similar to DisplayIndex. I also manually build my spreadsheets and whenever the layout of one of them changes I need to either make adjustments in code or through the Spread Designer.  Either way, you should not have to delete and re-add all columns.

Comment: Yes, the best way I found so far was to add the columns in the place I want using the spread designer and create an Enum in the code for each column index. This way I can give the columns a name and use that instead when populating the data. The benefit to this is that I can now rename the columns or add new ones and I just need to change the names around in the Enum given that the column type is correct.

Comment: Nice approach to the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I found so far was to add the columns in the place I want using the spread designer and create an Enum in the code for each column index. This way I can give the columns a name and use that instead when populating the data. The benefit to this is that I can now rename the columns or add new ones and I just need to change the names around in the Enum given that the column type is correct.